# Advanced Account Permissions

Tags: permissions

Is it possible to configure permissions to protect an accounts EOS balance with one key (held in cold storage) while allowing tokens that are getting airdropped to this account to be transferred out with another (hot) key?

Therefore allowing all tokens (excluding the main EOS balance) to be controlled by a separate key by default. Or do specific permissions need to be applied to the additional key on a case to case basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default all EOS accounts come with two permissions `owner` and `active` which can share the same keypair or be seperate.

From what you've described you can simple just make the `owner` key a cold storage keypair and use the `active` key for transferring Airdrops as they typically just look for the `@active` permission when executing `transfer` functions.

However, if you're looking for a delegated permission level where it can only transfer Airdrops and not the `EOS` token then you'd need a smart contract to handle that.